# PHP forking tool produce zombie process

Tags: php, fork, pcntl

I am new on PHP forking and I just copy this code sample from PHP.net. Basically I have a tool that monitor a device and save the data into a database. This tool is running in background.

here is my code:

```
for(;;)
{
//build connection
$conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
//select db
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

$sql='SELECT * FROM tbl';
$query=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$zpid=array();
while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{

    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    $execute=0;
    if ($pid == -1) 
    {
       echo("could not fork");
    } 
    elseif ($pid) 
    {

        $execute++;
        //pcntl_wait($status);
        if ($execute>=5)
        {
            $child=pcntl_wait($status);
            if($child)
            {
                $execute--;
                echo 'exited child'.$child;
            }

        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        $obj=new Monitor($res['ip'],$res['community_string'],$res['id']);
        $obj->execute();

        //save
        $obj->insert_data();
       sleep(10);   
       exit();
    }
}

mysql_close($conn);
sleep(60);
}
```

But when the tool run it will produce a zombie process. What will I do to prevent this zombie or defunct process on our server. Please help me. thanks in advance

Comment: what is **zombie process** ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 0):

A [zombie process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) is one which has terminated but not yet had its exit status read. This happens when its parent has not (yet) called [wait()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait_%28system_call%29) to read that exit status. [pcntl_wait()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-wait.php) here is that call, but it must be called *for each child*, most likely in a `while($execute)` after the forks. This code never calls it for the first 4 children.

Comment: thanks for your response..on my implementation I want max five multiple process running at same time. how will i track the first 4 children process be called wait() to read that exit status?